# Rails 3 User can choose between multiple form templates that post to same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, model

I'm still fairly new to rails and I'm not sure on how I should approach the following:
I have created a rails app where a user can post a task which has for example 2 basic attributes like a title and a task description. The task description is basically just a text area in which a user can enter anything he wants.

Now lets say that I know for a certain user that one of the tasks he frequently wants to post is a request for a transcription of an audio file. I want to create a specific form template for that user so that he does not have to type the entire task description every time. The only thing he needs to do is select the language and attach the audio file.

So my question is how can I allow for a user to select between multiple form templates, that post to the same model. Additionally a form template should be linked to a specific user so if there is a way to store these in a model that would be great.

Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That should be fairly easy to accomplish.

You can store some kind of type in a model, for simplicity lets assume you store it right in the `User` model as `form_type`.

In your application you can then implement all your different partials for the users:

- task

  - new.erb
  - form_partials

    - _default.erb
    - _special.erb
    - _special2.erb

and in your `new.erb` template you render the partial for the user:

```
= render "form_partial/#{current_user.form_type || 'default'}"
```

Comment: Would I be able to check in the create action which form template was used. If for example the transcription form was used the user adds the language and audio file, but I would still need to construct the task description myself and write it in the Task model. Or would I just let each form post to each own action which can make the task controller very large as I anticipate that I will be creating a number of templates for each user.

Comment: Whatever you think makes sense.